# Can I use appengine to push notifications locally?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, notifications, push

I want to make an appengine server that can push notifications to android devices locally, without publishing my app to google. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GCM (Google cloud Messaging), with or without Google App Engine, does not require you to publish your application on the play store as long as :

- The play store is installed on the device.
- A google account is configured on the device (not needed anymore for Android 4.0.4+).

See [GCM overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) (the first bullet list) for more details.

Comment: I want to make a server that gets data from devices, saves the data to mysql and pushes the data to devices. Any help?

Comment: The simplest workflow is to have the devices connect your server (maybe on appengine) to send an receive data. In this case GCM is only used to send a message saying "please contact me". It requires that you have a publicly accessible server (or at least from the devices)

Comment: Thanx, I've managed to send objects from android to the server, can you link me a tutorial on how to implement the server push code?

Comment: I used Google's own [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Comment: Is there anyway I can use this without an internet connection?

Comment: I think it is not possible to get GCM messages without internet connectivity, because GCM is based on the persistent connection between the Google Play Services (included in the play store apk) and Google's servers. For testing purpose it may be possible to fire GCM intents with adb (adb shell am ...) but I'm not sure at all

Answer (score 0):

GCM cannot be used without an internet connection.